# Create a ASP.NET Query string on my load without touching the URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How can I pass a paramator to another page without using Session variables or passing the Querysting in the URL?

I want to create a variable on my Page Load Event............

Comment: Have you tried posting a form variable?

Comment: How does that work, not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)